# What is wrong with this SQL statement

Tags: sql, mysql

The error is:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RA---SIN', 'DEC--SIN', 0.0,-90.0)' at line 1

```
INSERT INTO files_table (filename, folder, survey, telescope, author, observer, equinox, ctype1, ctype2, crval1, crval2) VALUES('H001_abcde_luther_chop.fits', 'C:\dev\data\FITS\surveys\', '', '','', -1.0, 'RA---SIN', 'DEC--SIN', 0.0,-90.0)
```

The statement that created the table was (the line breaks are just for ease of reading)

```
 create table files_table (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
 filename varchar(255), folder varchar(255), survey varchar(255), telescope varchar(255), 
 author varchar(255), observer varchar(255), equinox double, ctype1 varchar(255), ctype2
 varchar(255), crval1 double, crval2 double);
```

- Is it because I use ' instead of " - this hasn't troubled me before
- Is it due to the -- in RA---SIN and DEC--SIN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's because you are missing a value

You have 11 columns named and only 10 values

Comment: I don't see why this doesn't have 81 (one per view) upvotes. This should be the first thing you look at, no? Unless this is a sample, not directly copy/pasted code?

Comment: Once I used the backslashes as klausbyskov suggested then the error I got indicated this to be the problem.

Answer (score 12):

It is because of the backslash before the single quote. Escape your backslashes (like so `\\`) and it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're trying to insert RA--SIN into equinox column, which is of type double.

I believe you're missing an '', so the query would work like this:

INSERT INTO files_table (filename, folder, survey, telescope, author, observer, equinox, ctype1, ctype2, crval1, crval2) VALUES('H001_abcde_luther_chop.fits', 'C:\dev\data\FITS\surveys\', '', '','','' -1.0, 'RA---SIN', 'DEC--SIN', 0.0,-90.0)